# Custom Struct init in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, properties

```
struct User {
    var userID: String
    var nameSurname: String
    var email: String
    var password: Int
    var profileImageUrl: String

    var userDictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "userID": userID,
            "nameSurname": nameSurname,
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
            "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl,

        ]
    }
}

extension User {

    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard let userID = dictionary["userID"] as? String,
            let nameSurname = dictionary["nameSurname"] as? String,
            let email = dictionary["email"] as? String,
            let password = dictionary["password"] as? Int,
            let profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String else { return nil }

        self.init(userID: userID, nameSurname: nameSurname, email: email, password: password, profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl)
    }



}

let user = User(userID: "burak", nameSurname: "burak", email: "burak", password: 1234, profileImageUrl: "brk")
print(user.userDictionary)
```

I created a custom struct to hold my property and write init method to reach as dictionary but I want to add tweets property (without init or bypass the init) to reach my other struct but compiler gives me error. How can i initialize?

```
var tweets: [Tweet]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
self.init(userID: userID, nameSurname: nameSurname, email: email, password: password, profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, tweets: [])
```

Otherwise declare an empty array and add an explicit `init` method omitting `tweets`

Comment: I declared the empty array but because of self.init compiler gives "Cannot invoke 'User.init' with an argument list of type" that error

Comment: @johndouglas just add the next parameter (tweets) and pass an empty array

Comment: But if i declare an array, how i can reach properties of Tweet struct ?

Comment: I didn't propose an array, you did. Use a loop or `filter` or `map` depending on what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: I was trying to ask how i can bypass this property which is how to use without declaring in default initializer. Should i create custom init giving nil value to tweet property?

Comment: The rule is: The implicit *memberwise* initializer considers **all** declared members. Anything else you have to handle yourself. I'd recommend to declare this kind of array always as non-optional empty.